# Connecting a nib to files owner problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, view, nib

So I am upgrading my iPhone app to be universal.  I upgraded the project and than created a new nib for one of my classes.  I set the custom class for that nib to my viewController and dragged the view from files owner to the nib.  All worked fine.  But than the second time I ran it, I got the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the
"viewControlleriPad" nib but the view outlet was not set.'*** Call stack at first
throw:
```

So I disconnected view from the nib, than reconnected it and it worked.  So basically the pattern seems to be every time I link it, it works once.  This seems really weird.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new XIB that is created I suppose you have not associated the class of the `File's Owner` with the class of the view controller

Also you have not set the `view` outlet of the File's Owner.

Hope you get it.

If you need more help than please let me know.

EDIT:

Please refer to this question:

[Iphone sdk tabbar View outlet was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202009/iphone-sdk-tabbar-view-outlet-was-not-set)

**EDIT-2:**

[View Objects don't connect to the File's Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468310/view-objects-dont-connect-to-the-files-owner/5468364#5468364)

Comment: @Andrew: I think you need to clean up your project and then try to build and run.

Comment: I just tried that.  Same bug.  Works the first time.  Not the second

Comment: @Andrew: Check my anaswer I have edited my answer and added a link. I suppose that would be useful to you.

Comment: I looked at that before I asked my question and it didnt really help from what I skimmed

Comment: @Andrew: Also checkout my answer to the question posted in my answer under `EDIT-2` section.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before as well. It would be worth a try to try the following in this order:

1. Copy + paste your nib in xcode, rename the old one, name the new one to the old name
2. Rebuild the nib from scratch if it is not too much trouble
3. Restart your Mac
4. Examine the XML for the nib for any oddness

(#2 worked for me)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a nib with a ton of objects on it.  But thats the cost of doing business I guess